# Unbind and bind again a datagridview C# & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, unbind

I updated the data in the datagridview, but I'm not able to see the changes until I close and open the program, I tried this codes:

```
datagridview1.DataSourse = null; //to clear the datagridview
datagridview1.DataSource = dcontext.Empleados.ToList(); //to fill the datagridview again
```

But doing this I'm not able to see the changes that were made, I see the same datagridview1 I had in the beginning. I also tried a code that adds

```
something.Rows.Clear() //I dont remember the exact way it was written.
```

I have read that I need to unbind the datagridview and fill it(bind it) again.

May someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create a Binding Source

2.) Set the Datasource for this object to your Dataset Table.

3.) Set The datasource for your DatagridView as the Binding source Object.

```
Dataset ds = new Dataset();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource()
bs.Datasource = ds.Table[0];
datagridview1.Datasource = bs;
```

Comment: You can also use bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

Comment: BindingSource bds = new BindingSource() { DataSource = entities.Empleados.ToList() };

Comment: It says: Cannot find table 0.

Comment: I think you need to convert your List to DataTable

Comment: Look at CopyToDataTable() method

Comment: No, I'm still on it.